# ListView not displaying anything with no errors

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I'm using Volley to grab JSON data from a web page to then process said data and add it to a HashMap. After, I create a ListAdapter and feed it the HashMap.
All of this works, I get no errors but for some reason nothing actually shows up.

The ListView is nested in a LinearLayout fragment and the adapter uses a custom layout. The fragment renders fine.

onCreateView in the MainActivity

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_betriebe, container, false);

        mitgliederList = new ArrayList<>();
        mitgliederListView = view.findViewById(R.id.menu_betriebe_mitglieder_list);

        String url = getString(R.string.api_base_url) + "removed";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        JSONArray mitglieder;

                        try {
                            mitglieder = response.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < mitglieder.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject mitgliedObject = mitglieder.getJSONObject(i);

                                String mitglied_name = mitgliedObject.getString("mitglied_name");

                                Log.d("WBV", mitglied_name);

                                HashMap<String, String> mitglied = new HashMap<>();
                                mitglied.put("mitglied_name", mitglied_name);

                                mitgliederList.add(mitglied);
                            }

                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                    getActivity(),
                                    mitgliederList,
                                    R.layout.betriebe_list_item,
                                    new String[]{"mitglied_name"},
                                    new int[]{R.id.betriebe_list_item_mitglied_name});

                            mitgliederListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("WBV", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        );

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, "json_obj_req");

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_betriebe, container, false);
    }
```

The fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_betriebe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_betriebe_mitglieder_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The list item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/betriebe_list_item_mitglied_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="HalloTest"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use match_parent instead of fill_parent. The second is deprecated in Android

Comment: Can you do a e.printStackTrace() in your catch block to see if there is an exception

Comment: in ListView use match_parent instead of wrap_content

Comment: Changed to match_parent as suggested, no change. @kapsym I did, nothing prints past the for loop with the Log

Comment: I think the List Item Layout should have only <textView> instead of having inside the <LinearLayout> just  make a try.

Comment: @VeswanthRaju Tried it, sadly nothing still.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

1. make the oncreateView returns view object only after inflating layout
2. put the http reguest using volley in onViewCreate Method not onCreateView 
   method
3. call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); if you still have problems