# Fragment doesn't show changes

Tags: android, android-fragments

Follow up on: [ListView not displaying anything with no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505994/listview-not-displaying-anything-with-no-errors?noredirect=1#comment77973421_45505994)

I added a TextView to the fragment and set it's text property to unix time. The change does not show but reading and logging the property via getText shows that it has changed.

Do I need to force some kind of refresh for the fragment and if so, how do I do it?

Fragment class

```
public class MenuBetriebe extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mitgliederList;
    ListView mitgliederListView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_betriebe, container, false);

        mitgliederList = new ArrayList<>();
        mitgliederListView = view.findViewById(R.id.menu_betriebe_mitglieder_list);

        String url = getString(R.string.api_base_url) + "json/read/mitglieder";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        JSONArray mitglieder;

                        try {
                            mitglieder = response.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < mitglieder.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject mitgliedObject = mitglieder.getJSONObject(i);

                                String mitglied_name = mitgliedObject.getString("mitglied_name");

                                Log.d("WBV", mitglied_name); // works

                                HashMap<String, String> mitglied = new HashMap<>();
                                mitglied.put("mitglied_name", mitglied_name);

                                mitgliederList.add(mitglied);
                            }

                            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                            textView.setText(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

                            Log.d("WBV", textView.getText().toString()); // prints unix time but doesn't show on the fragment

                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                    getActivity(),
                                    mitgliederList,
                                    R.layout.betriebe_list_item,
                                    new String[]{"mitglied_name"},
                                    new int[]{R.id.betriebe_list_item_mitglied_name});

                            mitgliederListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("WBV", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        );

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, "json_obj_req");

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_betriebe, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Betriebe");
    }
}
```

Fragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_betriebe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_betriebe_mitglieder_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="442dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Test" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: @ user1826176 you are able to see the list item in the listView..?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran No, that was the original problem as linked in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a new view instead of returning the original with changes.

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_betriebe, container, false);
```

should have been

```
return view
```